# Matlab "single" precision vs C floating point?

Tags: c, matlab, floating-point, double, simulink

My Matlab script reads a string value "0.001044397222448" from a file, and after parsing the file, this value printed in the console shows as double precision:

```
  value_double =
      0.001044397222448
```

After I convert this number to singe using `value_float = single(value_double)`, the value shows as:

```
value_float = 
  0.0010444
```

What is the real value of this variable, that I later use in my Simulink simulation? Is it really truncated/rounded to `0.0010444`?

My problem is that later on, after I compare this with analogous C code, I get differences. In the C code the value is read as `float gf = 0.001044397222448f;` and it prints out as `0.001044397242367267608642578125000`. So the C code keeps good precision. But, does Matlab?

Comment: IEEE754 single precision floats have something like 6-9 decimal digits of precision. Trying to print out more is just noise.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the long string of digits when printing float in C. Most likely the stored precision is a lot smaller. What are the binary representations of the values when viewing them in C and Matlab debuggers? (assuming Matlab has one, I don't know Matlab)

Comment: It's best to just accept that most real values cannot be stored exactly in floating point format. Work to the precision you need, and don't expect accuracy beyond that. In C `double` is the 'default' precision. Work with that unless you need `long double` or there is some constraint that makes you use `float` (an old textbook example isn't). Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: The many digits result from the fact that computers use binary floating point numbers, not decimal ones. The decimal number 0.00**10443972**22448 is converted to the next possible binary number that apparently corresponds to (approximately) 0.00**10443972**42367267608642578125000. You can see that only 8 digits are the same as in your input. If you would add or subtract 1 least significant binary digit, the decimal representation might change by something around 0.00000000002 or even more. If you need higher precision use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: @user694733 C memory shows `28E4883A`.

Comment: @user694733 What exactly do you mean by "Don't be fooled by the long string of digits when printing float in C. Most likely the stored precision is a lot smaller." ? It sounds wrong but maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: @user694733 The memory should be interpreted as `0x3a88e428`.

Comment: This gives the binary representation: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: @Danijel Can it be that matlab only prints 7 decimals by default?

Comment: You might want to take a look a [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-format-for-numeric-values.html). I suppose you have the same output but matlab's output is truncated. I suspect if you use `format long` you'll have the same output as in C

Comment: In C when printing a float like `printf("%f\n", gf`);` only 6 decimals will be shown by default. So this will produce `0.001044` because the real value is rounded to a value with 6 decimals. In C you can do `printf("%.50f\n", gf`);` to get 50 decimals. Then the code produce `0.00104439724236726760864257812500000000000000000000`. Maybe Matlab is doing similar stuff

Comment: Danijel, try `printf("%a\n%a\n", 0.001044397222448, (float) 0.001044397222448);` for greater insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number 0.001044397222448 (like the vast majority of decimal fractions) cannot be exactly represented in binary floating point.

As a single-precision float, it's most closely represented as (hex) `0x0.88e428 × 2`<sup>`-9`</sup>, which in decimal is 0.001044397242367267608642578125.

In double precision, it's most closely represented as `0x0.88e427d4327300 × 2`<sup>`-9`</sup>, which in decimal is 0.001044397222447999984407118745366460643708705902099609375.

Those are what the numbers are, internally, in both C and Matlab.

Everything else you see is an artifact of how the numbers are printed back out, possibly rounded and/or truncated.

When I said that the single-precision representation "in decimal is 0.001044397242367267608642578125", that's mildly misleading, because it makes it look like there are 28 or more digits' worth of precision.  Most of those digits, however, are an artifact of the conversion from base 2 back to base 10.  As other answers have noted, single-precision floating point actually gives you only about 7 decimal digits of precision, as you can see if you notice where the single- and double-precision equivalents start to diverge:

```
0.001044397242367267608642578125
0.001044397222447999984407118745366460643708705902099609375
            ^
        difference
```

Similarly, double precision gives you roughly 16 decimal digits worth of precision, as you can see if you compare the results of converting a few previous and next mantissa values:

```
0x0.88e427d43272f8  0.00104439722244799976756668424826557384221814572811126708984375
0x0.88e427d4327300  0.001044397222447999984407118745366460643708705902099609375
0x0.88e427d4327308  0.00104439722244800020124755324246734744519926607608795166015625
0x0.88e427d4327310  0.0010443972224480004180879877395682342466898262500762939453125
                                        ^
                                     changes
```

This also demonstrates why you can never *exactly* represent your original value 0.001044397222448 in binary.  If you're using `double`, you can have 0.00104439722244799998, or you can have 0.0010443972224480002, but you can't have anything in between.  (You'd get a little less close with `float`, and you could get considerably closer with `long double`, but you'll never get your exact value.)

In C, and whether you're using `float` or `double`, you can ask for as little or as much precision as you want when printing things with `%f`, and under a high-quality implementation you'll always get properly-rounded results.  (Of course the results you get will always be the result of rounding the actual, *internal* value, not necessarily the decimal value you started with.) For example, if I run this code:

```
printf("%.5f\n", 0.001044397222448);
printf("%.10f\n", 0.001044397222448);
printf("%.15f\n", 0.001044397222448);
printf("%.20f\n", 0.001044397222448);
printf("%.30f\n", 0.001044397222448);
printf("%.40f\n", 0.001044397222448);
printf("%.50f\n", 0.001044397222448);
printf("%.60f\n", 0.001044397222448);
printf("%.70f\n", 0.001044397222448);
```

I see these results, which as you can see match the analysis above.
(Note that this particular example is using `double`, not `float`.)

```
0.00104
0.0010443972
0.001044397222448
0.00104439722244799998
0.001044397222447999984407118745
0.0010443972224479999844071187453664606437
0.00104439722244799998440711874536646064370870590210
0.001044397222447999984407118745366460643708705902099609375000
0.0010443972224479999844071187453664606437087059020996093750000000000000
```

I'm not sure how Matlab prints things.

---

In answer to your specific questions:

> What is the real value of this variable, that I later use in my Simulink simulation? Is it really truncated/rounded to `0.0010444`?

As a float, it is really "truncated" to a number which, converted back to decimal, is exactly 0.001044397242367267608642578125.  But as we've seen, most of those digits are essentially meaningless, and the result can more properly thought of as being about 0.0010443972.

> In the C code the value is read as float gf = 0.001044397222448f; and it prints out as 0.001044397242367267608642578125000

So C got the same answer I did -- but, again, most of those digits are not meaningful.

> So the C code keeps good precision. But, does Matlab?

I'd be willing to bet that Matlab keeps the same internal precision for ordinary floats and doubles.

Comment: “I'm not sure how Matlab prints things.” MATLAB likely uses the same C library to present numbers. I don’t know for sure of course, but they don’t have a reason to reimplement things like that.

Comment: Note that your last example is done on `double` precision type since this is the default type for decimal numbers in c. It explains why you have 67 decimals stored in your representation and a precision of about 15 decimals.

Comment: "I'd be willing to bet that Matlab keeps the same internal precision for ordinary floats and doubles." Indeed in [matlab doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) we see that matlab, like C complies to IEEE754 for single and double representation. Which means they have the exact same internal precision.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB uses IEEE-754 binary64 for its double-precision type and binary32 for single-precision. When 0.001044397222448 is rounded to the nearest value representable in binary64, the result is 4816432068447840•2<sup>−62</sup> = 0.001044397222447999984407118745366460643708705902099609375.

When that is rounded to the nearest value representable in binary32, the result is 8971304•2<sup>−33</sup> = 0.001044397242367267608642578125.

Various software (C, Matlab, others) displays floating-point numbers in diverse ways, with more or fewer digits. The above values are the exact numbers represented by the floating-point data, per the IEEE 754 specification, and they are the values the data has when used in arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1):

#### All single precisions should be the same

So here is the thing. According to documentation, both [matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) and [C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/float-and-double-in-c) comply with the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard. Which means that there should not be any difference between what is actually stored in memory.

You could compute the binary representation by hand but according to [this](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)(thanks @Danijel) handy website, the representation of `0.001044397222448` should be `0x3a88e428`.

The question is how precise is your representation? It is a bit tricky with floating point but the short answer is **your number is accurate up to the 9th decimal** and **has decimal represented up to the 33rd decimal**. If you want the long answer see the tow paragraphs at the end of this post.

#### A display issue

The fact that you are not seeing the same thing when you print does not mean that you don't have the same bits in memory (and you should have the exact same bytes in memory in C and MATLAB). The only reason you see a difference on your display is because the print functions truncate your number. If you print the 33 decimals in each language you should not have any difference.

- To do so in matlab use: `fprintf('%.33f', value_float);`
- To do so in c use `printf('%.33f\n', gf);`

#### About floating point precision

Now in more details, the question was: how precise is this representation? Well the tricky thing with floating point is that the precision of the representation depends on what number you are representing. The representation is over 32 bits and is divide with 1 bit for the sign, 8 for the exponent and 23 for the fraction.

The number can be computed as `sign * 2^(exponent-127) * 1.fraction`. This basically means that the maximal error/precision (depending on how you want to call it) is basically `2^(exponent-127-23)`, the 23 is here to represent the 23 bytes of the fraction. (There are a few edge cases, I won't elaborate on it). In our case the exponent is `117`, which means your precision is `2^(117-127-23) = 1.16415321826934814453125e-10`. That means that your single precision float should represent your number accurately up to the 9th decimal, after that it is up to luck.

#### Further details

I know this is a rather short explanation. For more details, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate?noredirect=1&lq=1) explains the floating point imprecision more precisely and [this website](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) gives you some useful info and allows you to play visually with the representation.